# Splitting data into different groups by date for each unique customer

Tags: python, pandas

I have the customer journeys for 100,000 customers. A costumer journey maps out every interaction a customer has in our program, from the date they enrolled to when they left the program or went inactive.

```
customer_id| event_name  | event_date

1          | entered     |2019-07

1          | purchase = 2|2019-07

1          | purchase = 2|2019-07

1          |went_inactive|2019-02

2          | entered     |2019-07

2          | purchase = 0|2019-07

2          | purchase = 2|2019-07

3          | went_inactive|2018-08
```

I am trying to split the data into test and train based on the date

I want to create a function to split the data so that I have a group of customers who were active in Jan 2019. The data spans from 2010 to current time. The people in group X are customers who have an inactive data after Jan 31st 2019 and those who do not have an inactive date. Then for all the customers in group X I want to create a subset of patients who went inactive in Feb 2019.

I do not know how to filter through each unique customer journey and only take people in the defined date.

The goal is to create a function that can look through the customer journey for the 100,000 patients and then split the data into groups. **So X would have customer 1 + 2 but not 3.**  Appreciate all help.

Comment: Can you please show what you are expecting in X? Based on the sample dataset you provided..

Comment: I want a list of customer IDs that went inactive after Jan 2019 plus those who never went inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Start from computing the set of *customer_id* for customers who went
inactive in *2019-01* or earlier:

```
inact = set(df.query('event_name == "went_inactive" and event_date <= "2019-01"')\
    .customer_id)
```

For your sample data it is `{3}`.

Then compute the result as:

```
act = list(set(df.customer_id).difference(inact))
```

The result is just `[1, 2]`.

Or maybe just *set(...)* is enough? Later you may e.g. want to
retrieve rows for active customers, executing:

```
df.query('customer_id in @act')
```

It will run when *act* is either a *list* or a *set*.